# Better way to make sidebars?

Tags: lists, wrapfigure

I am producing pages for a website using pdfTeX.  My style is to use lots of bulleted lists and also lots of cutouts (sidebars such as many magazines use).  I am using wrapfig.sty for the cutouts; the version I have is version 3.6 from 2003.  It is very erratic and gets along especially badly with bulleted lists.  Right now I have made a work-around by defining my own lists, but they are not nearly as nice as the LaTeX system.  I have tried tweaklist but it seems to make things worse, not better.

Is there anything better than wrapfig?  It occured to me that one of the new typesetting systems that are TeX with additional capabilities (such as XeTeX and ConTeXt) might make the situation easier.  Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Can you post an image that shows the target layout that you are after?

Comment: ConTeXt's layer's handling would probably be of some help... but why do this in tex? would an image editor (like gimp/photoshop) be better for this? or why not do it in HTML in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

I am not completely sure what exactly are you trying to achieve, and what do you mean by "sidebars", so i cannot really give you a solution for your problems, but I will try to provide some pointers with hope that they will turn out helpful.

First, the `wrapfig` package, as well as all other LaTeX packages providing a way to wrap text around figures, does not play nice with lists.  That fact is well known and even mentioned in the wrapfig documentation.

XeTeX will not help you with layout issues.  XeTeX is a TeX engine that allows you to use your system fonts in your document, but it provides no layout macros of its own.  Instead, you use it with other formats and macros, such as LaTeX and ConTeXt.

ConTeXt may indeed be a good choice for you.  It is in general much more flexible than LaTeX for creating different page layouts, and it has a build in mechanism for placing graphics at various locations on the page.  Its lists work generally well with text wrapped around figures. However, it is different from LaTeX, it has somewhat different conventions and syntax, so you will have to learn new things if you are used to LaTeX.

If you want to stick with LaTeX, you have several options. There are several packages that place material at specific locations on the page.  Perhaps the most powerful is the `pgf` package. You can also create complicated custom page designs with the `flowfram` package.  I suggest you look at the documentation for these two packages and see if they solve your problem.